How to find the intersection angle of diagonals of a fixed quadrilateral?
In this question here,
$
\angle DBA = 62^\circ$, $\quad \angle DBC= 59^\circ$, $\quad \angle BDA = 44^\circ$, $\quad \angle BDC = 68^\circ$
is given and we are asked to find $\angle DOC$
one way to solve this would be to play around and finding out the C is the excentre of $\triangle ABD$ in reality, so  $AC$ will be the angle bisector of $\angle DAB$ and we can easily find $\angle DAB$ from $\triangle ABD$ and then we can easily find $\angle DOC$. But I wanna know what if C was NOT the excentre, i,e what if the given angles were different? How would we then approach the problem? I think the question would still be valid as quadrilateral would still be fixed{as both $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle CBD$ are fixed}, but I can't think of any way to solve it can someone please help me with this?

You can create 4 equations with 4 unknowns to calculate ODC and OCD.

but how can we calculate $\angle OCD$ ?. I am not able to get it

The final solution is $81^\circ$. I’ll write solution when I get home. :)

@Shyam Next time, please draw image that has angles approximately equal to angles used in the problem. With the drawing that you supplied, you cannot do anything… it’s completely distorted. Learn to use Geogebra, it pays off.

It seems that the general solution could be made only by the use of trigonometry.


Based on angles given in the problem it's easy to calculate angles $\angle BAC=74^o$, $\angle BCD=53^o$, $\angle CBL=59^o$. By coincidence (carefully chosen values for angles) it turns out that $\angle DBC=\angle CBL$. So line BC is the angular bisector of the outer angle of triangle $\triangle ABD$ at point $B$.
Now draw the angular bisector $IA$ at point A of the outer angle of the same triangle $\triangle ABD$. It's easy to calculate that $\angle IAM=\angle IAD=\angle DBC=53^o$.
These two outer angle bisectors ($IA$ and $CB$) of triangle $\triangle ABD$ intersect at point $G$. By well known (and quite simple theorem about triangle bisectors), line BG must be a bisector of interior angle $\angle BDA$. So $\angle GDA=\angle GDB=\frac12 \angle BDA=22^o$. Again, by a lucky circumstance, it turns out that $\angle CDG=\angle IDG=\angle CDB+\angle BDG=68^o+22^o=90^o$
Voila!
So triangle $\triangle IDG$ is right-angled. Now that you have all these angles it's easy to see that triangles $\triangle ABG$, $\triangle CBD$, $\triangle AID$ and the big one, $\triangle CIG$, are all similar, because they have the same angles ($53^o$, $59^o$ and $68^o$).
Now use the fact that:
$$\triangle AID \sim \triangle CIG$$
Because of that:
$$\frac{ID}{IG}=\frac{IA}{IC}\tag{1}$$
Also note that triangles $\triangle IAC$ and $\triangle IDG$ share the same angle ($\angle I$). Because od this and (1):
$$\triangle IAC \sim \triangle IDG$$
...and because of that, triangle $\triangle IAC$ is right angled triangle too.
Now it's all easy:
$$\angle DAO=\angle IAO-\angle IAD=90^o-53^o=37^o$$
In triangle $\triangle DAO$, external angle $\angle DOC$ is given by sum of the other two interior angles:
$$\angle DOC = \angle DAO + \angle ADO = 37^o+44^o$$
$$\bbox[yellow, 5pt, border: 2px dotted red]{\angle DOC = 81^o}$$
Exactly what I promised in my comment a few hours ago :)
This problem has many hidden beauties in it: for example, point $K$ is the orthocenter of big triangle $\triangle CIG$. Line $IK$ is therefore perpendicular to side $CG$ and passes through point $B$. At the same time, point $K$ is the center of inscribed circle of triangle $\triangle ABD$.
Very nice problem, indeed.

Here is a slight generalization of the given constellation of points and angles:

Let $x,y$ be two angles with $x+y < 90^\circ$. (This condition may be relaxed, but the picture is different.) Start with the segment $BD$,
and construct

on one side of it two rays intersecting in a point $A$, such that the formed angles are $2x$ in $B$, and $2y$ in $D$,

and on the other side two rays intersecting in a point $C$, such that the formed angles are $90^\circ - x$ in $B$, and $90^\circ-y$ in $D$.



Question: Which is the angle formed by the segments $AC$ and $BD$?
Note: The given problem occurs for
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= 31^\circ\ ,\\
y &= 22^\circ\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Solution:
Draw the angle bisectors in $B,D$ in $\Delta ABD$, let $J$ be their intersection point, the incenter of this triangle. The third angle bisector is thus $AJ$, which separates the angle in $A$ in this triangle in two equal angles with measure $90^\circ-x-y$ each. In particular $\widehat{AJB}=90^\circ +y$, constrained by the sum of the angles in $\Delta AJB$ to be $180^\circ$. On the other side the quadrilateral $BJDC$ is cyclic, having two right opposite angles, they sum to $180^\circ$, the center of the circumcircle is the mid point of $JC$, etc. - so we know in particular the angle
$\widehat{BJC}=\widehat{BDC}=90^\circ -y$.
The angle $\widehat{AJC}$, computed as $\widehat{AJB} + \widehat{BJC}$ is $(90^\circ+y)+(90^\circ-y)=180^\circ$, so $A,J,C$ are colinear.
We are now in position to compute the smaller angle between the diagonals $AC,BD$ of the quadrilateral $ABCD$, it is
$$
180^\circ-
\widehat{CAB}-
\widehat{ABD}=
180^\circ-(90^\circ-x-y)-2x=90^\circ -(x-y)\ .
$$
In our given numeric case $x-y=9^\circ$, so the wanted angle is $90^\circ-9^\circ=81^\circ$.
$\square$
